# Caret train using auto_arima_model results in "Error: Please use column names for `x`"

Tags: r, r-caret, arima

Documentation is here

https://rdrr.io/github/sfeuerriegel/caret.ts/man/auto_arima_model.html

```
library(caret)

# without exogenous variables

library(forecast)
data(WWWusage) # from package "forecast"
df <- data.frame(y = as.numeric(WWWusage))
df$y

lm <- train(y ~ 1, data = df, method = "lm", trControl = trainDirectFit())
summary(lm)
RMSE(predict(lm, df), df)

arima <- train(y ~ 1, data = df, method = auto_arima_model(), trControl = trainDirectFit())
```

OR https://rdrr.io/github/sfeuerriegel/caret.ts/man/train.ts.html

```
library(caret)

library(forecast)
data(WWWusage)

class(WWWusage)
str(WWWusage)

arima <- train(WWWusage, method = auto_arima_model(), trControl = trainDirectFit())
```

Error

```
Error: Please use column names for `x`
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first error, you should check [here](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/717). Basically it says that if you want to fit a model without any exogenous variable this is the right syntax:

```r
# packages
library(caret)
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

nullModel(y = WWWusage)
#> Null Classification Model
#> 
#> Call:
#> nullModel.default(y = WWWusage)
#> 
#> Predicted Value: 137.08
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

[Here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/feature-selection-using-univariate-filters.html) they author wrote that: `caret` contains a model function called `nullModel` that fits a simple model that is independent of any of the predictors. For problems where the outcome is numeric, the function predicts every sample using the simple mean of the training set outcomes. For classification, the model predicts all samples using the most prevalent class in the training data.

Probably there is another problem due to the fact that `auto_arima` is not one of the models available with `caret`. You can check the list of all available models with

```r
sort(names(caret::getModelInfo()))
#>   [1] "ada"                 "AdaBag"              "adaboost"           
#>   [4] "AdaBoost.M1"         "amdai"               "ANFIS"              
#>   [7] "avNNet"              "awnb"                "awtan"              
#>  [10] "bag"                 "bagEarth"            "bagEarthGCV"        
#>  [13] "bagFDA"              "bagFDAGCV"           "bam"                
#>  [16] "bartMachine"         "bayesglm"            "binda"              
#>  [19] "blackboost"          "blasso"              "blassoAveraged"     
#>  [22] "bridge"              "brnn"                "BstLm"              
#>  [25] "bstSm"               "bstTree"             "C5.0"               
#>  [28] "C5.0Cost"            "C5.0Rules"           "C5.0Tree"           
#>  [31] "cforest"             "chaid"               "CSimca"             
#>  [34] "ctree"               "ctree2"              "cubist"             
#>  [37] "dda"                 "deepboost"           "DENFIS"             
#>  [40] "dnn"                 "dwdLinear"           "dwdPoly"            
#>  [43] "dwdRadial"           "earth"               "elm"                
#>  [46] "enet"                "evtree"              "extraTrees"         
#>  [49] "fda"                 "FH.GBML"             "FIR.DM"             
#>  [52] "foba"                "FRBCS.CHI"           "FRBCS.W"            
#>  [55] "FS.HGD"              "gam"                 "gamboost"           
#>  [58] "gamLoess"            "gamSpline"           "gaussprLinear"      
#>  [61] "gaussprPoly"         "gaussprRadial"       "gbm"                
#>  [64] "gbm_h2o"             "gcvEarth"            "GFS.FR.MOGUL"       
#>  [67] "GFS.LT.RS"           "GFS.THRIFT"          "glm"                
#>  [70] "glm.nb"              "glmboost"            "glmnet"             
#>  [73] "glmnet_h2o"          "glmStepAIC"          "gpls"               
#>  [76] "hda"                 "hdda"                "hdrda"              
#>  [79] "HYFIS"               "icr"                 "J48"                
#>  [82] "JRip"                "kernelpls"           "kknn"               
#>  [85] "knn"                 "krlsPoly"            "krlsRadial"         
#>  [88] "lars"                "lars2"               "lasso"              
#>  [91] "lda"                 "lda2"                "leapBackward"       
#>  [94] "leapForward"         "leapSeq"             "Linda"              
#>  [97] "lm"                  "lmStepAIC"           "LMT"                
#> [100] "loclda"              "logicBag"            "LogitBoost"         
#> [103] "logreg"              "lssvmLinear"         "lssvmPoly"          
#> [106] "lssvmRadial"         "lvq"                 "M5"                 
#> [109] "M5Rules"             "manb"                "mda"                
#> [112] "Mlda"                "mlp"                 "mlpKerasDecay"      
#> [115] "mlpKerasDecayCost"   "mlpKerasDropout"     "mlpKerasDropoutCost"
#> [118] "mlpML"               "mlpSGD"              "mlpWeightDecay"     
#> [121] "mlpWeightDecayML"    "monmlp"              "msaenet"            
#> [124] "multinom"            "mxnet"               "mxnetAdam"          
#> [127] "naive_bayes"         "nb"                  "nbDiscrete"         
#> [130] "nbSearch"            "neuralnet"           "nnet"               
#> [133] "nnls"                "nodeHarvest"         "null"               
#> [136] "OneR"                "ordinalNet"          "ordinalRF"          
#> [139] "ORFlog"              "ORFpls"              "ORFridge"           
#> [142] "ORFsvm"              "ownn"                "pam"                
#> [145] "parRF"               "PART"                "partDSA"            
#> [148] "pcaNNet"             "pcr"                 "pda"                
#> [151] "pda2"                "penalized"           "PenalizedLDA"       
#> [154] "plr"                 "pls"                 "plsRglm"            
#> [157] "polr"                "ppr"                 "PRIM"               
#> [160] "protoclass"          "qda"                 "QdaCov"             
#> [163] "qrf"                 "qrnn"                "randomGLM"          
#> [166] "ranger"              "rbf"                 "rbfDDA"             
#> [169] "Rborist"             "rda"                 "regLogistic"        
#> [172] "relaxo"              "rf"                  "rFerns"             
#> [175] "RFlda"               "rfRules"             "ridge"              
#> [178] "rlda"                "rlm"                 "rmda"               
#> [181] "rocc"                "rotationForest"      "rotationForestCp"   
#> [184] "rpart"               "rpart1SE"            "rpart2"             
#> [187] "rpartCost"           "rpartScore"          "rqlasso"            
#> [190] "rqnc"                "RRF"                 "RRFglobal"          
#> [193] "rrlda"               "RSimca"              "rvmLinear"          
#> [196] "rvmPoly"             "rvmRadial"           "SBC"                
#> [199] "sda"                 "sdwd"                "simpls"             
#> [202] "SLAVE"               "slda"                "smda"               
#> [205] "snn"                 "sparseLDA"           "spikeslab"          
#> [208] "spls"                "stepLDA"             "stepQDA"            
#> [211] "superpc"             "svmBoundrangeString" "svmExpoString"      
#> [214] "svmLinear"           "svmLinear2"          "svmLinear3"         
#> [217] "svmLinearWeights"    "svmLinearWeights2"   "svmPoly"            
#> [220] "svmRadial"           "svmRadialCost"       "svmRadialSigma"     
#> [223] "svmRadialWeights"    "svmSpectrumString"   "tan"                
#> [226] "tanSearch"           "treebag"             "vbmpRadial"         
#> [229] "vglmAdjCat"          "vglmContRatio"       "vglmCumulative"     
#> [232] "widekernelpls"       "WM"                  "wsrf"               
#> [235] "xgbDART"             "xgbLinear"           "xgbTree"            
#> [238] "xyf"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can also add new models to that list following the instructions reported here: http://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html

Comment: hrmm... Well thanks for the direction but that second link looks like a whole lot more work than just coding the time series cross folds myself which is what I did.